# Excel VBA deleting many different rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 365 and am trying to delete many difference rows and have some working code but it is very inefficient. Deleting 500 out of about 2000 rows takes a long time compared to manually filtering the column, highlighting the rows and deleting so I thought to get all the rows needing to be deleted and do it in one shot but have not been successful. My working code is:

```
' When cell contains TRUE, erase that row
For i = LastRow To firstDataRow Step -1
    If Cells(i, eraseCol).Value = True Then
        sheetdata.Rows(i).Delete
        LastRow = LastRow - 1
    End If
Next
```

What I am trying to do which doesn't work:

```
For i = LastRow To firstDataRow Step -1
    ' collect all rows to be deleted in range r
    If Cells(i, eraseCol).Value = True Then
        r = Union(Rows(i), r)
    End If
Next
r.Delete
```

Any idea how I can get all rows to be deleted in r and do it at once? Or perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: `r.EntireRow.Delete` after this, there is no undo (no `Ctrl`-`z`) and the undo buffer will be wiped. NO going back.

Comment: `If r Is Nothing Then
  Set r = Rows(i)
Else
  Set r = Union(Rows(i), r)
End If`

Comment: `If Cells(i, eraseCol).Value = True Then` is redundant, this will usually do `If Cells(i, eraseCol).Value Then`

Comment: Awesome. I incorporated all 3 suggestions and it worked perfectly. It went from taking ages to a couple of seconds. If you put your comments as an answer I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
' collect rows to be deleted into range r

' Alternate loop construct using iterator (partial code - diff only)
' Dim i as Range
' For Each i in <column range> ' i.e. <EraseCol>2:<EraseCol>10000
'     If i.value Then
'         If r Is Nothing Then
'             Set r = i
'         Else
'             Set r = Union(r, i)
'         End If
'     End If
' Next i

' No need to step backward, this will only scroll up one time.
For i = firstDataRow to LastRow
    If Cells(i, eraseCol).Value Then
        If r Is Nothing Then
            Set r = Rows(i)
        Else
            Set r = Union(r, Rows(i))
        End If
    End If
Next i
r.EntireRow.Delete ' NO UNDO - wipes undo buffer
```

Comment: In your alternate loop construct, should Union(r,i) be similar to below that doing "Set r = Union(r, i)"?

Comment: yes. I left out any code that matched, just want to show you there was no Cell() dereference with the iterator in the union operation.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Give this a shot:

```
For i = LastRow To firstDataRow Step -1
    ' collect all rows to be deleted in range r
    If Cells(i, eraseCol).Value Then 
        If r is Nothing Then set r = cells(i,eraseCol) else: Set r = union(r,Cells(i,eraseCol))
    End If
Next

r.EntireRow.Delete
```

*N.B* - since you are only collecting cells into a range, you can loop forward if you desire; but looping backward will still work too

Comment: Thanks for this as well. It uses the same technique as the other solution, but I found your formatting of the inner condition interesting. I never thought to represent it that way.